# Interface best practices

Tags: c#, oop, interface, dependency-injection, dependencies

I'm working on an application that is split in the following way (simplified a bit)

```
App
|
Framework
|
Data (Persistance)
|
Data.Couchbase
```

Inside App we're setting up the DI container and registering which concrete implementations will be used when a particular interface is needed.

I.e. IUserRepository in the Data namespace will be fulfilled by CouchbaseUserRepository in the Data.Couchbase namespace. In the future if we swap out the persistance layer with another technology, say Mongo, we could update the DI registration and it would be fulfilled by say MongoUserRepository

All well and good....

**Question 1**

There is an obvious benefit to providing interfaces that cross system boundaries but whatabout *within* the Data.Couchbase namespace itself. Is there any point in having an ICouchbaseUserRepository interface if it doesn't provide any extra functionality itself? It seems as though if we register IUserRepository -> CouchbaseUserRepository that should be good enough? Similary within concrete implementations is there any point in splitting those components up further into interfaces that probably wont be swapped out

**Question 2**

Similarly is it worth having a bunch of interfaces in Framework whos only purpose is to proxy on to interfaces in Data, therefore App can have a dependency only on Framework and not have to also depend on Data. I can see the advantage.... actually maybe I can't..... it seems like we're going to have hundreds of interfaces in the framework whereby we could just have a dependency on 'Data' especially if these assemblies are going to live on the same tin

Cheers

Comment: Two questions in one question is probably going to get some resistance.

Comment: Why? There's plenty of questions on SO with 2,3,4+ questions in one. Both are related and it makes more sense than splitting into 2 and repeating the introduction for each...

Answer (score 1):

### Answer 1

CouchbaseUserRepository implementing IUserRepository makes great sense.  All of your application logic uses only the interface, so that if you later switch to Mongo you only have to make your MongoUserRepository implement the same interface.

### Answer 2

If you're building a large application, definitely go with two layers of interfaces: db level, and framework level.  If it's not so big, it might be too much.  In either case it would not be incorrect to create interfaces at your framework level as well.

Comment: For answer 1, how about an CouchbaseUserRepository implementing an 'ICouchbaseUserRepository' which is just an empty interface deriving from IUserRepository - that's where I feel it might be going a bit too far

Answer 2: What's the added value in this case though?

Comment: There's no value added by having ICouchbaseUserRepository.  The value added in the second part is that the app is operating functionality at the level of your business logic, arather than directly with a database.  You wouldn't want to have direct db interaction in your app code.

Comment: You're right that it's not good to interact directly with a database - that's why the Data tier just contains interfaces to the concrete implementations in Data.Couchbase. What I was getting at in question 2 is why try to abstract away the Data namespace behind the framework - either way you're going to be accessing data related interfaces from the app... maybe the answer is for Data to logically sit alongside Framework rather than being accessed through it

Answer (score 1):

Both of these questions fall into a coding and design style realm.  As such they might be a better fit for the Programmers site.  (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

When dealing with issues of design the leading practice is clear -- you should have an interface that defines you DB tier and then you can inject a new type of data access with ease.

Where there is no functional need for an interface (as you describe in your questions) the need for the interface is to provide clarity -- it is coding style which makes your system clearer.

For example, in a contact management system it might make sense to define an interface to a database / system "object" which defines a contact.  Then in addition make interfaces for people and organizations.  This is helpful in the context of this application.  Creating such interfaces for a document management system would make no sense.  For both of them you would want the interface defined for DB injection.

You as the designer and programmer have decide -- there are no hard and fast rules when it comes to style choices in designing a system.